# Error in MySQL using python and XAMPP: MySQL Connection not available

Tags: python, html

I'm making a discount card system, there will be payments using stripe and registration, I'm using MySQL and XAMPP for the database, but I'm having a problem, it's giving me this error: MySQL Connection not available, already I researched and I've been trying to solve it for 2 days, I think the error is not in the code, because everything was working and when I finished I did the commit in my github in the private repository, then I went to do the credit card part discount, then this error happened, I went back to my backup and it kept giving the same error and it wasn't giving before, this is the python code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, flash
import datetime
from flask import session
import mysql.connector
import stripe

stripe.api_key = "api_key"

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'secret_key'
app.config['SESSION_PERMANENT'] = False
app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'filesystem'
app.config['PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME'] = datetime.timedelta(days=10)

try:
    db_connection = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="host",
        user="user",
        password="password",
        database="database"
    )
    print("Conectado")
except mysql.connector.Error as e:
    print("Conexão falhou:", e)
db_connection.close()


def email_exists(email):
    cursor = db_connection.cursor()
    verificar_query = "SELECT id FROM usuarios WHERE email = %s"
    cursor.execute(verificar_query, (email,))
    existe = cursor.fetchone()
    db_connection.close()

    return existe is not None


@app.route('/form', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.form.get('email')  # Obtém o email do formulário

        if email_exists(email):
            flash("O email já está em uso. Não é possível cadastrar.")
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            name = request.form.get('name')
            email = request.form.get('email')
            password = request.form.get('password')
            nascimento = request.form.get('dataNascimento')
            telefone = request.form.get('tel')
            rg = request.form.get('rg')
            cpf = request.form.get('cpf')
            endereco = request.form.get('adress')
            cidade = request.form.get('city')
            numero = request.form.get('num')
            uf = request.form.get('top')
            cep = request.form.get('cep')
            complemento = request.form.get('com')

            cursor = db_connection.cursor()

            sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (name, email, password, nascimento, endereco, cidade, cpf, telefone, numero, uf, rg, cep, complemento) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
            valores = (name, email, password, nascimento, telefone, rg, cpf, endereco, cidade, numero, uf, cep, complemento)
            app.config['PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME'] = datetime.timedelta(days=10)
            cursor.execute(sql, valores)
            db_connection.commit()
            cursor.close()

    return render_template('registro-associado.html')


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def html():
    return render_template('index.html')


def login(name, email, password, cpf):
    cursor = db_connection.cursor()

    query = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE name = %s AND email = %s AND password = %s AND cpf = %s"
    cursor.execute(query, (name, email, password, cpf))
        
    # user = cursor.fetchone()
    # sql_query = """
    # UPDATE usuarios SET numero_cartao = CONCAT(FLOOR(1000 + (RAND() * 9000)), ' ', FLOOR(1000 + (RAND() * 9000)), ' ', FLOOR(1000 + (RAND() * 9000)), ' ', FLOOR(1000 + (RAND() * 9000)));
    # """
    # cursor.execute(sql_query,)

    cursor.close()
    
    db_connection.close()

    return user


@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login_page():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.form['name']
        email = request.form['email']
        password = request.form['password']
        cpf = request.form['cpf']

        user = login(name, email, password, cpf)

        if user:
            session['name'] = user[1]
            session['email'] = user[2]
            session['password'] = user[3]
            session['cpf'] = user[7]
            # session['numero_cartao'] = user[15]
            flash(f"Login bem-sucedido! Bem-vindo, {user[1]}", 'success')
            return redirect(url_for('cartao'))
        else:
            flash("Credenciais inválidas. Tente novamente.", 'error')

    return render_template('login.html')


def make_payment(client_secret):
    try:
        payment_intent = stripe.PaymentIntent.confirm(client_secret)
        if payment_intent.status == "succeeded":
            name = request.form['name']
            email = request.form['email']
            password = request.form['password']
            cpf = request.form['cpf']
            user = login(name, email, password, cpf)
            cursor = db_connection.cursor()
            # query = "UPDATE usuarios SET cartao = 1 WHERE id = %s"
            # cursor.execute(query, (user[0],))
            # sql_query = "UPDATE usuarios SET numero_cartao = CONCAT(FLOOR(1000 + (RAND() * 9000)), ' ', FLOOR(1000 + (RAND() * 9000)), ' ', FLOOR(1000 + (RAND() * 9000)), ' ', FLOOR(1000 + (RAND() * 9000)));"
            # cursor.execute(sql_query, (user[0],))
            db_connection.commit()
            db_connection.close()
        if payment_intent.status == "requires_payment_method":
            name = request.form['name']
            email = request.form['email']
            password = request.form['password']
            cpf = request.form['cpf']
            user = login(name, email, password, cpf)
            cursor = db_connection.cursor()
            # query = "UPDATE usuarios SET cartao = 0 WHERE id = %s"
            # cursor.execute(query, (user[0],))
            db_connection.commit()
            db_connection.close()
    except stripe.error.StripeError as e:
        print(e)


client_secret = "client_secret"
make_payment(client_secret)


@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    session.clear()
    flash("Logout realizado com sucesso.", 'success')
    return redirect(url_for('index'))


@app.route('/index')
def page():
    if 'name' in session:
        return render_template('index.html', name=session['name'], email=session['email'], password=session['password'], cpf=session['cpf'])
        # return render_template('index.html', name=session['name'], email=session['email'], password=session['password'], cpf=session['cpf'], number=session['numero_cartao'])
    else:
        return "Acesso negado. Faça o login primeiro."
    

@app.route('/cartao')
def cart():
    if 'name' in session:
        return render_template('cartao.html', name=session['name'], email=session['email'], password=session['password'], cpf=session['cpf'])
        # return render_template('index.html', name=session['name'], email=session['email'], password=session['password'], cpf=session['cpf'], number=session['numero_cartao'])
    else:
        return "Acesso negado. Faça o login primeiro."
    

@app.route('/cartao')
def cartao():
    return render_template('cartao.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I tried to make the discount cards, create their number and put it on the website, but I got this error: MySQL Connection not available.

Comment: Are you getting "Conexão falhou:" in the logs?

Comment: yes I am receiving it in the log, but only after I register, when I start the program I am receiving "Conectado"